# C++ ⎼ Two similar functions but performing very differently

Tags: c++, data-structures, quicksort

I am writing a quicksort program. For that I need to partition the array. The partitioning is done by a function `paritionIt()`. I wrote a code of partitioning the array which is as follows:

```
int partition(int beg,int end,double key)
{
    int pLeft = beg;
    int pRight = end-1;
    while(pLeft<pRight)
    {
        while(array[++pLeft]<key);
        while(array[--pRight]>key);
        if(pLeft<pRight)
            swap(pLeft,pRight);
    }
    swap(pLeft,end-1);
    return pLeft;
}
```

This block seems to work to work fine when executed in isolation. However, when ran along with the other functions, it seems to generate wrong answer. The following code given to me makes all the problems vanish but it doesn't seem much different from my code.

```
int partitionIt(int left, int right, double pivot)
{
    int leftMark = left; //right of first elem
    int rightMark = right - 1; //left of pivot
    while(true)
    {
        while( theVect[++leftMark] < pivot ) //find bigger
        ; // (nop)
        while( theVect[--rightMark] > pivot ) //find smaller
        ; // (nop)
        if(leftMark >= rightMark) //if pointers cross,
            break; // partition done
        else //not crossed, so
            swap(leftMark, rightMark); //swap elements
    } //end while(true)
    swap(leftMark, right-1); //restore pivot
    return leftMark; //return pivot location
} //end partitionIt()
```

The block seems to be similar to mine but is giving the right answer whereas mine is not. Can you please me by telling what's the difference between `partition()` and `partitionIt()`.

Comment: So if you replace your code (the first block) with the second block, all of your functions work as expected?

Comment: I don't see any functional difference between those two pieces of code.

Comment: Yep...in fact, my entire code is matching with the code given in the book ( except for the variable names ).

Comment: @MatsPetersson:- Should I put the entire code?

Comment: Do you have any thing odd? As in, `using namespace std` or any `#define`s?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen  I have included `using namespace std` but no `#define`s

Comment: Try removing that line and see if it fixes it (obviously you'll need to fix references to `std::` objects).

Comment: The two functions are clearly different if called with `left + 1 == right`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you please elaborate your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is where you're breaking out of your looping structure.

In your code, you're making two conditional checks, whereas in the given code, you're only making one.

Assume you've been iterating through the loop for a while. (No pun intended).

You'll hit this code:

```
 if(pLeft<pRight)
                swap(pLeft,pRight);
```

Then you'll hit the bottom of the while loop, come back to the top, and then check again if `pLeft<pRight`. If this isn't true, we exit the loop.

In the given code, you perform the swap, but then you do the following:

```
while( theVect[++leftMark] < pivot ) //find bigger
    ; // (nop)
    while( theVect[--rightMark] > pivot ) //find smaller
    ; // (nop)
```

You *then* check to see if you break out of the loop.

This seems to be where the difference lies.

Edit: To clarify - what happens if `while(pLeft>=pRight)` when you first enter the loop?

In the given code, you continue through the `while` loop until it breaks, but in your code, you never enter the body of the loop.

Comment: But in my code, after I swap the values, why am I still going to the top of the loop and not in the given code ? I thought that in any loop, we always go to the top of the loop to check if your condition is still true or not. But in your answerm you are stating that this is not the case. Please explain.

Comment: @kusur Check the edit - the difference is where you perform your conditional check and break out of the loop.

Comment: In any loop, we do go to the top of the loop and check the condition. In the given code, that happens to always evaluate to true. In your code, it doesn't.

Comment: In that case, I am not entering the loop at all. So, there is no partitioning taking place. But this is happening when I have only one element to partition which,I think, doesn't really make sense. Won't I be returning the `leftmark`?

Comment: @kusur Exactly. You won't enter the loop at all. In the given code, you will, you'll increment rightMark and leftMark (as James Kanze said), and THEN perform the swap and return.

In your code, you only swap and return, without incrementing leftMark and rightMark.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see immediately is that the functions will
behave differently if called with `left + 1 == right`: your
function will not enter the loop, but will return `beg`; the
function from the book *will* enter the loop, thus incrementing
`leftMark` and decrementing `rightMark` before doing the final
swap and returning `leftMark`.